# If not BigO, then BigOmega?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, performance

So if a function or running time is not BigO of f(n), can we say its BigOmega of f(n)?

Comment: `BigOmega` is superlative: `MegaO` is sufficient, no need to make it bigger... (of course, this is a joke !)

Comment: I think it depends on your function - *do* you know the Big-O of your function?

Comment: you may be interrested in the wikipedia article regarding [BigOmega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: if it depends on the function, then the answer to the question is "no". At least, I interpret the question to mean, "is it true that for any two functions f, g, either f is O(g) or f is Big-Omega(g)?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. For example the function

```
        / n^n if 2|n
 f(n) = |
        \ 0   otherwise
```

is neither in `O(n)` nor in `Ω(n)`: for any values `N` and `c` there will always be a value `n > N`, such that `f(n) > c*n` (so it can't be in `O(n)`) and another value `m > N` such that `f(m) < c*m` (so it can't be in `Ω(n)`).

Comment: @sepp2k: could be from one of the two(!) people who upvoted ybungalobill.

Comment: To complete the example, you could still say that in this case `f(n)` is in `O(n^n)` and `Ω(1)`, correct? (Or at least if the result on odd numbers was `1` instead of `0`)

Comment: Bad answer, non familiar with known functions

Answer (score 3):

No, not necessarily.

As usual, with such theoretical topics you can consider some *funny* functions. Let's take a function `g` that returns the value `1/n` for all odd inputs and for an even input `n` it returns `n*n`.

This function is not in BigO of f(n)=n (the identity function). This should be clear, as you get n*n results.

It is, however, also not in BigOmega of f(n)=n, because for very large numbers you are not guaranteed that g(n) >= k*f(n).

Answer (score 2):

Even if the functions are monotone increasing, i.e., n < m -> f(n) \leq f(m), then it's still not true that f(n) \neq O(g(n) implies f(n) = \Omega(g(n)).

Consider for example f(n) = g(n)^2 for n even and g(n-1) for n odd, and g(n) = f(n)^2 for n odd and f(n-1) for n even, with f(0) = 2, g(0) = 2.

Both are monotone increasing, but neither is big-oh of the other (grow very fast).